# Use Rails Migrations to delete an index without knowing its name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, indexing, migration

I have a table with a compound index that wasn't created through a rails migration. Now, I need to create a rails migration that will delete this index and create a new one, but I don't necessarily know what the name of the index will be.

I know that it is possible to get a list of table names and column names within a migration step. Is it possible to get a list of index names on a particular table? Or, looking at it another way, is it possible to delete *all* indexes on a table? Or is the only option to write my own database-specific SQL queries to get this info?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get details of all the indexes on a table with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes('tablename')
```

This returns an array of `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::IndexDefinition` objects, each of which has a `#name` and `#columns` method.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @showaltb's great answer, here is a complete migration to remove all indexes on a table, without knowing their names:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes('tablename').each do |index|
  remove_index 'tablename', name: index.name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the info directly from the database.  If you're using MySQL:

```
>> select TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME from information_schema.statistics WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';
```

You only need to replace the *your_database_name* bit.  You'll need priviledges for the information_schema database (or be logging in as root).

Comment: This seems to be mysql-specific; it doesn't work on postgresql for example. I think the OP was trying to avoid this.